# From excel sheets to OrderedDict

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, ordereddictionary

I have an excel file with some sheets (let's say 3) with different shape and content.
I am trying to:

1) load every sheet with openpyxl since I want to see formulas.

2) Store every Loaded Sheet in a different pandas DataFrame.

3) All those 3 DataFrames should be saved in an OrderedDict in the form 'sheet_name':DataFrame.

This is the code I have been working on so far:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd
import os
from collections import OrderedDict
# Define the path of my file
Base_Dir = ''
File_Read = 'readfile.xlsx'
path_read = os.path.join(Base_Dir, File_Read)
# Load Workbook, store sheet names and number of sheets
wb = load_workbook(filename = path_read)
sheet_names = wb.get_sheet_names()
sheet_number = len(wb.sheetnames)
# Loop that stores every excel sheet in an ordered dictionary in the form 'sheet_name':DataFrame
od = OrderedDict()
for sheet_name, sheet_position in sheet_names, sheet_number:
    name = sheet_names['{}'.format(sheet_position)]
    sheet_ranges = wb[name]
    od['{}'.format(sheet_name)] = pd.DataFrame(sheet_ranges.values)
```

But I keep receiving this error:

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Do you have any hints on this? because I'm feeling kind of stuck at the moment.

Thanks so much in advance for any help,

Comment: Please share the sample input data.

Comment: It can be for example an .xlsx file like this: 

in "Sheet1" --> "Cell A1" = 1;

in "Sheet2" --> "Cell A1:B2" = "a" in every cell;

in "Sheet3" --> "Cell A1:C3" = "3" in every cell.